# What are possibly synonyms for "hands-on experience" on a technical subject?

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

I would like to know what are possibly synonyms for:

"hands-on experience on ..." to be placed on technical documentation or a resume, for instance I have a phrase with some duplication as

"With 5 plus years of professional experience, and hands-on experience using C#", (experience is mentioned twice).

Comment: What other kind of experience than 'hands-on' is there? I mean, why can't you say ""With 5 plus years of professional experience, including C#".?

Comment: I meant "hands-on" => used in real project

Comment: There's **practical** versus **theoretical** …

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks for your comment, so I could rephrase it without using "experience" twice in such a short sentence?

Comment: Well, I don't know what *professional* means in this context. Nor do I know what practical C# experience would be as opposed to theoretical C# experience.

Comment: sorry, I add here a bit of context... I would like to add this sentence on my resume (software developer), "professional" means for making a living, not an hobby, by practical, used in real business project

Comment: @Radex In that case, I don't know what *hands-on* experience means with respect to programming—or how it is different from professional.

Answer (score 1):

The following terms come to mind:

- Real-world experience
- Battle proven
- Hard-won experience
- Tangible experience
- Practical experience
- Experience in the trenches
- X amount of billable hours doing Y for Z company